# How to wrap text in Auto Scroll List Box in thinter?

Tags: python, tkinter, tkinter-canvas, tkinter-layout

Please tell how to wrap text in Auto list box.
The text is not displayed fully in list item, I want it to automatically change line when it reaches the end of line.
I know I have to do wrap=WORD but not able to get where should I add it.
Thankyou in advance.

Image of UI, text going outside:

[image]

Code snippet

```
class AutoScroll_ListBox:
    def __init__(self, master):
        frame = Frame(master)
        frame.pack(fill=X, padx=10, pady=1)
        instructions()

        self.listbox_log = Listbox(
            frame, bg="black", height=12, fg="cyan", font=('Times', 45))
        self.scrollbar_log = Scrollbar(frame)

        self.scrollbar_log.pack(side=RIGHT)
        self.listbox_log.pack(fill=X)

        self.listbox_log.configure(
            yscrollcommand=self.scrollbar_log.set)
        self.scrollbar_log.configure(command=self.listbox_log.yview)

        # Just to show unique items in the list
        self.item_num = 0

    def addToChatBox(self, speaker, msg):
        self.listbox_log.insert(END, speaker+"       " + msg)

        self.listbox_log.select_clear(self.listbox_log.size() - 2)
        self.listbox_log.yview(END)

        self.item_num += 1

    def onSpeak(self):
        print("Listening..")
        msg = take_user_input()
        self.addToChatBox("User :", msg)
        result = Logic.reply_to_query(self, msg.lower())
        self.addToChatBox("Liam :", result)

    def onAdd(self):
        msg = messageVar.get()
        self.addToChatBox("User :", msg)
        result = Logic.reply_to_query(self, msg.lower())
        self.addToChatBox("Liam :", result)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My Solution:

What I did was after every 60 characters I made a new list item, because my font will remain constant, there the characters fitting in a line will always remain constant.
This is how it looks now.

[Solved problem screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U0nqw.png)

Answer (score 1):

The `Listbox` widget doesn't support wrapping. If you want text to be able to wrap, you'll have to use something else such as a `Text` widget.

Comment: Can you please tell how can I update my code ?